# MySQL processor usage on a Xeon on Linux

Tags: mysql, processor

I run a LAMP server - Ubuntu 12.10 on a Intel Xeon 4 core proc.

I notice that mysqld only uses one core leaving the other 3 idle.

The server gets some pretty high loads at times and during these brief periods of high loads everything drags and only one core is utilized.

How can I configure MySQL to use all 4 cores and distribute its workload better?

Furthermore, I got a dual proc board in anticipation of this but omitted the second proc for now, so this should be addressed for this future upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core)?

Setting [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) to 0?

RolandoMySQLDBA said:

> Once you set innodb_thread_concurrency to 0, you can set
>   innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads (both since MySQL
>   5.1.38) to the maximum value of 64. This should engage more cores.